# Rust - Why to import a trait when it's already implemented on struct

Tags: rust

In the below example from std docs, we're importing the read trait from `std::io::prelude::*` although the trait is implemented on `File`.

Why can't we implicitly use the `f.read()` method on `File` instance? Does importing the trait solve any specific problem?

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut buffer = [0; 10];

    // read up to 10 bytes
    let n = f.read(&mut buffer)?;

    println!("The bytes: {:?}", &buffer[..n]);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I don't know the specific reasoning, but I would imagine it's closely related to this fact: Types do not know all of the traits they implement, as implementations can be defined in crates they're not aware of. Likewise, traits do not know all of the types that implement them.